# Firebase orderByKey doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object.

```
{
featured-routines: {
 1465895195: "-LALALA"
 1465898164: "-KK7pEednXoUBszpqCmg"
 1465898185: "-KK9xFyA8skOvSLhaHWq"  
}
}
```

and I try to get them by calling:

```
Database.getFeaturedReference()
        .orderByKey()
        .addValueEventListener(routineListener);
```

The result should be in ascending order, but it's not. It's totally random. It isn't even in the same order as it shows in Dashboard GUI:

```
{ key = featured-routines, value = {1465898185=-KK9xFyA8skOvSLhaHWq, 1465895195=-LALALA, 1465898164=-KK7pEednXoUBszpqCmg} }
```

Anyone knows how to get them in the right order?

Comment: `"key = featured-routines"` ... so, well it is ordered by key ... and there is only one key: "featured-routines" ... in other words you are getting data at wrong level

Comment: So how can I then target child keys?

Comment: I even refactored object to"
featured-routines {
 1465898185 {
 featured_at: 1465898185,
 routine_id: "-KK9xFyA8skOvSLhaHWq"
],
 1465898285 {
 featured_at: 1465898285,
 routine_id: "-KK7pEednXoUBszpqCmg"
}
}

and call them by : `Database.getFeaturedReference().orderByChild("featured_at")` order is still messed up.

Comment: `Database.getFeaturedReference()` ... is your method which prolly returns  Query object from firebase lib ... it is hard to say how to change your code if we don't know what `Database.getFeaturedReference()` does

Comment: does it return `your_db.firebase.com/some_container/featured-routines` or `your_db.firebase.com/some_container/`

Comment: getFeaturedReferece() returns `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("featured-routines")`.

'featured-routines' is in the root or object tree.

Comment: on firebase database console you can export a .json file with all your data. can you provide it? it will help understand whats going on.

Comment: You might as well assume that the json I provided is all the data there is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the children in the order you request them, you have to either use a `ChildEvenListener` or `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` within your `ValueEventListener`:

```
    ValueEventListener routineListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Systme.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
            }
        }
        ...
    });
```

Comment: So it does not matter, that when I log the whole snapshot the data looks in random order? It will order it in client?